# How to pass string from one form to another

Tags: datagridview, c++-cli

I have this problem, I manage pass int value from one form to another, but I cannot do that with a string value (string can also came from user input). When code is run it passes nothing. Below form1 code:

```
 public: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    int aaa ;
    String^ dur = "Hello";
    dataGridView1->Rows[0]->Cells[0]->Value = dur;
}
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    form2 ^ form2 = gcnew form2();
    form2->aaa=10;
    form2->dur;
    form2->ShowDialog();
}
```

In Form2 program whrites a number but not a title. Code below:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    String^ fileName = dur +".txt";
    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
    sw->WriteLine(aaa);
    sw->Close();
}
```

Comment: This line does nothing: form2->dur;  Try something like: form2->dur = "Hello";

Comment: I know that, but what should I do if string comes from user interface?